# Print a javascript variable in Backbone template from view using handlebar templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, backbone-views

Here is the detail of my issue.

**Step 1:**

Inside my rails show.html.erb file I have saved a javascript variable.

```
var js_current_service_name = '<%= @application_service.service.name %>';
```

This one is working fine and visible through Source code.

**Step 2:**

While initializing my Backbone Controller and view I have passed this as a parameter

```
@collection_plan = new Fastconnect.Collections.AppServicePlans(js_service_plans)

@appServicePlansIndexView = new Fastconnect.Views.AppServicePlansIndex({collection: @collection_plan, current_service_name: js_current_service_name})
```

**Step 3:**

It successfully arrives at the backbone view:

```
class Fastconnect.Views.AppServicePlansIndex extends Backbone.View
    el: '#backbone-app_service_plans'
    template: HandlebarsTemplates['service_plans/index']
    inprogress_class: '#service_plans_body'

    limit: 20

    initialize: (options) ->
      @current_service_name = options.current_service_name

      console.log(@current_service_name)

      @collection.bind 'reset', @reset, @
      @reset() if @collection.length > 0

    render: ->
      @$el.html @template()

    _elementFromModel: (model) ->
      view = new Fastconnect.Views.AppServicePlansItem model: model

      res = view.render().el
      $(res).hide()
      return res

    addOne: (model) ->
      res = @_elementFromModel(model)
      @$el.find(@inprogress_class).append $(res).fadeIn('slow')

    addAll: ->
      @collection.first(@limit).forEach(@addOne, @)

    clearTable: ->
      @$el.find(@inprogress_class).html('')

    reset: ->
      @render()
      @addAll()

    events:
      "keyup #search_input" : "filterCollection"

    filterCollection: ->
      search = $('#search_input').val()

      if search
        console.log("clear karo1")

        filtered = @collection.filterCollection(search)
        @clearTable()
        console.log("clear karo")
        filtered.forEach(@addOne, @)
      else
        @addAll()
```

**Step 5:**

In my index.hbs I have to this in my index.hbs. How do I print this or put an if condition. I have done both these things before  with {{  }} or {{{ }}} but they are not working now.

This is my index.hbs

```
<div class="row service_plans connections">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>{{ current_service_name }} Suppliers {{{ current_service_name }}} </h4>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">

      <div class="row main_inner_nav">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-group">
             <input id="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="type a Plan Name, Supplier Name or Lodgement Email">
           </div>
        </div>
      </div> 

      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Plan Name</th>
            <th>Connection Type</th>
            <th>Billing Method</th>
            <th>Usage</th>
            <th>Supplier Name</th>
            <th>Lodgement Email</th>
            <th>Assignment</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="service_plans_body">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The strange thing is I have an item.hbs file in which this brackets work fine.

This is my item.hbs file.

```
<td class="">{{ attributes.plan_name }}</td>
<td class="">{{ attributes.connection_type }}</td>
<td class="">{{ attributes.billing_method }}</td>
<td class="">{{ attributes.usage }}</td>
<td class="">{{ attributes.supplier }}</td>
<td class="">{{ attributes.lodgement_email }}</td>
{{#if attributes.current_supplier }}
    <td class=""> {{{ attributes.current_supplier_label }}} </td>
{{else if completed }}
<td></td>
{{else }}
    <td class="">
      <a href="" class="button assign_supplier_row" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#suppliermodal" data-id="{{ attributes.id }}" data-name="{{ attributes.supplier }}">Assign</a>
    </td>
{{/if}}
```

**Final Query:** I need to print a few variables in index.hbs the way I am printing stuff in item.hbs.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: My CoffeeScript is weak, but it looks like you're not passing any data to your `@template` method.

Comment: @76484 You're right, they'd have to say something like `@template(attributes: whatever)` or `@template attributes: whatever` to get data into the template.